# SWIFT: Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range

Tags: swift

I have been trying for the last 4 hours on how to fix this error. It builds perfectly runs fine. But when I swipe up on the feed to reload it crashes.

What it is supposed to do is, you have your home feed with all the latest posts, and to reload that page you swipe up. It displays a spinning wheel at the top upon swiping up and it removes all images from the feed and brings the new and updated ones back. (that was a really bad explanation).

Any help is appreciated. and I have provided my whole class just to make sure I don't miss out on any code that I should be sending.

Here is my FeedController.swift class

```
import Firebase

private let reuseIdentifier = "Cell"

class FeedController: UICollectionViewController  {
    
    // MARK: - Lifecycle
    
    private var posts = [Post]()
    var post: Post?
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        configureUI()
        fetchPosts()
    }
    
    //MARK: - Actions
    
    @objc func handleRefresh() {
        posts.removeAll()
        fetchPosts()
    }
    
    @objc func handleLogout() {
        do {
            try Auth.auth().signOut()
            let controller = LoginController()
            controller.delegate = self.tabBarController as? MainTabController
            let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: controller)
            nav.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
            self.present(nav, animated: true, completion: nil)
        } catch {
            print("DEBUG: Failed to sign out")
        }
    }
    
    // MARK: - API
    
    func fetchPosts() {
        guard post == nil else { return }
        
        PostService.fetchPosts { posts in
            self.posts = posts
            self.collectionView.refreshControl?.endRefreshing()
            self.collectionView.reloadData()

        }
    }
    
    // MARK: - Helpers
    
    func configureUI() {
        collectionView.backgroundColor = .white
        
        collectionView.register(FeedCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        
        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Logout",
                                                           style: .plain,
                                                           target: self,
                                                           action: #selector(handleLogout))
        navigationItem.title = "Feed"
        
        let refresher = UIRefreshControl()
        refresher.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleRefresh), for: .valueChanged)
        collectionView.refreshControl = refresher
    }
}

// MARK: - UIcollectionViewDataSource

extension FeedController {
    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return post == nil ? posts.count : 1
    }
    
    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! FeedCell
        
        if let post = post {
            cell.viewModel = PostViewModel(post: post)
        } else {
            cell.viewModel = PostViewModel(post: posts[indexPath.row])
        }
        
        return cell
    }
}

// MARK: - UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout

extension FeedController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        
        let width = view.frame.width
        var height = width + 8 + 40 + 8
        height += 50
        height += 60
        
        return CGSize(width: width, height: height)
    }
}
```

This is the line that's giving me the error (after I refresh)

`cell.viewModel = PostViewModel(post: posts[indexPath.row])`

Comment: On this line `return post == nil ? posts.count : 1` why are you returning 1 instead of 0?

Comment: What is the property `post` for? It's never been set and seems to make no sense anyway? And what is `PostViewModel`?

Comment: Why are you using `post` as you are not setting any value in `post` anywhere?

Comment: try to move `posts.removeAll()` inside `PostService.fetchPosts { posts in` so you empty the array only when you get something back.

Comment: For extra info, I am using post in a different class that handles the firebase stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Ans: When you are not getting any data, display dummy data or return 0 cells.

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if post.count == nil { return 0 } else { return post.count
}
```

Issue: If you return 1 if the data is nil, which means the compiler returns a cell. when each element of that cell is tied to a particular value in an array. Since the post array is nil, it returns the index of the range exception.

Comment: Hello, I have given it a try but to no fix, I still get a crash.

it's giving me the error here cell.viewModel = PostViewModel(post: posts[indexPath.row]) with the thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range

Comment: @ZachLudwick you have initialized post variable  "var post: Post?". But, you are not getting any value into it. you didn't write any code to get value in "post" yet. implement that first. get the callback value into "post" array in the current class.

Answer (score 0):

override func collectionView(_collectionView:UICollectionView,cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

```
let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! FeedCell

if let post = post {
    cell.viewModel = PostViewModel(post: post)
} else {
    if posts.count != 0{
        cell.viewModel = PostViewModel(post: posts[indexPath.row])
    }
}
return cell
```

}